# Passing property values with spaces to Ant

Tags: powershell, ant

I'm trying to pass a space-separated value `$env:tt` to Ant under PowerShell

`$env:tt="val1 val2"`

Here are the commands I've tried:

`ant '-DTest="$env:tt"'`

`ant -DTest=$env:tt`

With the above commands, Ant doesn't interpret $env:tt. The value of test becomes $env:tt.

`ant -DTest="$env:tt"`

I got the following response under PowerShell

```
PS C:\> ant -DTest="$env:tt"
>>
```

It seems that this command is not finished, and PowerShell expects me to enter some characters to terminate the command.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: does this help : `ant  "-dest=$env:tt"`

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

variables are expanded inside [double quotes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-herestrings.aspx) but not when inside single quotes.

`ant "-dest=$env:tt"`